# How to initialize empty tensor with certain dimension and append to it through a loop without CUDA out of memory?

Tags: python-3.x, append, pytorch, tensor

I am trying to append tensors (t) generated in a for-loop to a list [T] that accumulates all these tensors. Next, the list [T] requires to be converted into a tensor and needs to be loaded onto GPU.

```
        b_output = []

        for eachInputId, eachMask in zip(b_input_ids, b_input_mask):
            # unrolled into each individual document
            # print(eachInputId.size()) # individual document here

            outputs = model(eachInputId, 
                    token_type_ids=None, 
                    attention_mask=eachMask)


            # combine the [CLS] output layer to form the document
            doc_output = torch.mean(outputs[1], dim=0) # size = [1, ncol]

            b_output.append( doc_output )

        t_b_output = torch.tensor( b_output )
```

Another method that I tried was initializing a tensor {T} with fixed dimensions and appending the tensors (t) to it from the for-loop.

```
        b_output = torch.zeros(batch_size, hidden_units)
        b_output.to(device) # cuda device

        for index, (eachInputId, eachMask) in enumerate(zip(b_input_ids, b_input_mask)):
            # unrolled into each individual document
            # print(eachInputId.size()) # individual document here

            outputs = model(eachInputId, 
                    token_type_ids=None, 
                    attention_mask=eachMask)


            # combine the [CLS] output layer to form the document
            doc_output = torch.mean(outputs[1], dim=0) # size = [1, ncol]

            b_output[index] = doc_output
```

Doing either of this produces this error:

```
RuntimeError: CUDA out of memory. Tried to allocate 20.00 MiB (GPU 0; 11.17 GiB total capacity; 10.65 GiB already allocated; 2.81 MiB free; 10.86 GiB reserved in total by PyTorch)
```

I assume this is because of appending the tensors (that are on the GPU) to a list (of course not on the GPU) and then trying to convert the list into a tensor (thats not on the GPU).

What could be done to append those tensors to another tensor and then load the tensor to GPU for further processing?

I will be grateful for any hint or information.

Comment: Do you know which line is causing the memory overflow? If it is the `t_b_output = torch.tensor( b_output )`, chaining the `torch.tensor` to `torch.stack` might solve the issue.

Comment: Yes, it is that line that's causing the problem. I tried both, torch.tensor and torch.stack, but neither worked.

Answer (score 2):

Try using `torch.cat` instead of `torch.tensor`. You are currently trying to allocate memory for you new tensor while all the other tensors are still stored, which might be the cause of the out of memory error. Change :

```
t_b_output = torch.tensor( b_output )
```

with:

```
t_b_output = torch.cat( b_output )
```

Hope this help

Comment: Thank you for the answer @N, however, the error springs up before .cat function is applied on the b_output list. The error occurs at b_output.append( doc_output )

Comment: Then it might be that your GPU memory is not big enough to store all your tensors. One thing you could try is to move your tensors from GPU to CPU before appending them to the list: `b_output.append( doc_output.to('cpu') )`. And reloading them on GPU one by one for further processing. However, it will be computationally expensive.